# Access SQL: How to set date to year?

Tags: sql, database, date, ms-access

How to set the news.time to year? I want to find 2012 year.

```
SELECT
    news.id, 
    news.Categoryid, 
    news.newsid, 
    news.Languageid, 
    news.createtime, 
    news.tags, 
    news.topic, 
    news.sub_topic, 
    news.[time], 
    news.content_s, 
    [Language].Languagename, 
    Category.Categorysubid
FROM
    (
        news 
        INNER JOIN
        [Language] 
            ON news.Languageid = [Language].Languageid
    ), Category
```

I tried this code but it not work:

```
SELECT
    news.id, 
    news.Categoryid, 
    news.newsid, 
    news.Languageid, 
    news.createtime, 
    news.tags, 
    news.topic, 
    news.sub_topic, 
    news.[time], 
    news.content_s, 
    [Language].Languagename, 
    Category.Categorysubid
FROM 
    (
        news 
        INNER JOIN
        [Language] 
            ON news.Languageid = [Language].Languageid
    ), Category
WHERE ( YEAR(news.[time]) = YEAR(?) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The year is a number, so it doesn't need any conversion:

```
WHERE ( YEAR(news.[time]) = 2012)
```

You can also use a date interval, which may be more efficient:

```
WHERE (news.[time] >= #20120101# and news.[time] < #20130101#)
```